# Set the contents of a column to the same value

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have the following function setup in my domain base:

```
    public void SetProcessFlag<T>(bool flag)
    {
        string tableName = typeof(T).ToString().Replace("MyBase.Core.Domain.", "");

        string sql = string.Concat("update ", tableName, " set ImportProcessed = '" , (flag?"1":"0"), "';");
        Framework.FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
            .CreateSQLQuery(sql)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
    }
```

I have a mapping with the schema of "Catalog" and the table of "Parts".  It contains a mapped column "ImportProcessed" as Bool.

Now when I want to set the column "ImportProcesses" to true I call is like the this:

```
new Parts().SetProcessFlag<Parts>(true);
```

This works just fine.  I don't like having to assume that the folder the declaration of the record set has the same name of the schema.

Is it possible to do the same thing with?:

```
Framework.FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
.CreateCriteria(typeof(T))
....
```

Or even a more elegant method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HQL, it is made for this

```
var rowsaffected = session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Part p SET p.Processed=:processed")
    .SetParameter(":processed", true)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Interesting method.  But I still a problem here.  Normally the name space of your tables are dbo.TableName.  What if the name space is Catalog.TableName?  Example Catalog.Parts.  How would you go about not having to specifically state the "Catalog" part of the name space.  That way you can make this a good domain base.  Not all tables live in "Catalog" name space.

Comment: the Part in the query shown is the class name and is not used directly. It is the mapping of part which specifies the table (and schema/catalog) name, you can set it per mapped class or global for all mapped classes.